# How to count specific Attribute value using XQuery?

Tags: java, xquery

Below is the XML File -

```
<Title t="1">
    <Book sub="Computers"/>
    <Book sub="Engg."/>
</Title>
<Title t="2">
    <Book sub="Computers"/>
</Title>
<Title t="1">
    <Book sub="Computers"/>
    <Book sub="Engg."/>
    <Book sub="Medical"/>
</Title>
```

What will be the XQuery to count the occurrences of "Computers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the provided XML fragment is wrapped in a single top element so that this becomes a well-formed XML document, then the following XPath expression (not using `//`):

```
count(/*/*/*/@sub[. = 'Computers'])
```

produces the wanted result.

Answer (score 2):

Counting all the `sub` attributes that have `'Computers'` as value:

```
count(//@sub[. = 'Computers'])
```

Comment: won't it require FLWOR..? I have to assign the count to a variable and then display it.. I missed this information in the main message.

Comment: No, a *FLWOR* expression in XQuery is just an expression, like `42` or a function call. It's not a required part of the query like `SELECT` in SQL.